# Can't connect volume to Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, docker, rasa, azure-container-instances

I tried to deploy my Rasa chatbot in an Azure Container Instance using a YAML file and Azure CLI. Although it runs smoothly locally using the local wsl2 volume path /var/lib/docker/volumes/, when in cloud it appears to have the following problem.

Inside the rasa/rasa:3.x.x image there is a dockerfile layer that creates a Volume /tmp that contains metadata and python autographs. But when I upload the image to the cloud, while it seems that there is a connection with Azure File Share, this /tmp folder is NOT created. As you can see in the images below, inside the properties of the ACI, the File Share volume appears to function well.

[ACI with Azure File Share connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSw18.png)

[Empty Azure File Share directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIM1X.png)

[Docker VOLUME [/tmp] layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPaRE.png)

Below is my deploy-aci.yml used for the:
az container create --resource-group  --file deploy-aci.yml

```
apiVersion: '2019-12-01'
location: northeurope
name: rasa-core-server
properties:
  containers:
  - name: rasa-core-server
    properties:
      environmentVariables: []
      image: rasaregistry.azurecr.io/rasa-core-server:1.0.0   
      ports:
      - port: 5005
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 2
          memoryInGB: 8
          gpu:
            count: 1
            sku: K80          
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /rastorage
        name: rasa-storage
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: Always
  ipAddress:
    type: Public
    ports:
    - port: 5005
    dnsNameLabel: rasa-core-server
  imageRegistryCredentials:
  - server: rasaregistry.azurecr.io
    username: test123
    password: test456 
  volumes:
  - name: rasa-storage
    azureFile:
      sharename: rasa-storage
      storageAccountName: test123
      storageAccountKey: test456
tags: {}
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

**Is there something i am missing about mounting a File Share volume to a Linux Azure Container Instance?**

I have already read the documentation about mounting with Azure File Share
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hey @RahulKumarShaw-MT and thank you for your help! I believe you are right as the server is up and running fine when i train and create this /tmp folder INSIDE the built image. The issue was happening only when i loaded model weights which requires an already existed /tmp folder (and probably existed metadata from the same server). TL;DR Server is running with training from inside the built image but can't be loaded from model weights inside the built image. SOLVED.

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT - please don't post comments asking for people to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I upload the image to the cloud, while it seems that there is
> a connection with Azure File Share, this /tmp folder is NOT created.

the `/tmp` folder is mapped with your host even you are taking image of that running container you won't able save that `/tmp` folder as image and can't able to see in the Azure Container Instance.

Only Partition or folder which you have created for local container can able to see in Azure Container Instance because they are not mapped/attached with your host.

Another more important things be notice apart from above suggestion : Below Suggestion is taken from [***Mount an Azure file share in Azure Container Instances***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files)

> If you mount a share into a container directory in which files or
> directories exist, the mount obscures files or directories, making
> them inaccessible while the container runs.